# Split string using regular expression in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm beginner in php and I have string like this:

```
$test = http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads//godzilla-article2.jpghttp://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads/life-goes-on-wpcf_300x111.jpg
```

And I want to split string to array like this:

```
Array(
[0] => http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads//godzilla-article2.jpg
[1] => http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads/life-goes-on-wpcf_300x111.jpg
)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

```
$test = 'http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads//godzilla-article2.jpghttp://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads/life-goes-on-wpcf_300x111.jpg';
$testurls = explode('http://',$test);
foreach ($testurls as $testurl) {
    if (strlen($testurl)) // because the first item in the array is an empty string
    $urls[] = 'http://'. $testurl;
}
print_r($urls);
```

Answer (score 4):

You asked for a regex solution, so here you go...

```
$test = "http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads//godzilla-article2.jpghttp://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads/life-goes-on-wpcf_300x111.jpg";
preg_match_all('/(http:\/\/.+?\.jpg)/',$test,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

The expression looks for parts of the string the start with `http://` and end with `.jpg`, with anything in between. This splits your string exactly as requested.

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads//godzilla-article2.jpg
    [1] => http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads/life-goes-on-wpcf_300x111.jpg
)
```

Comment: +1 for actually using a regex. But this requires `.jpg` at the end.

Comment: @Antony - well yes, but that's what the OP's input contains. Given the lack of solid criteria, I based it on what was in the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can split them if they are always like this vith substr() function reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php but if they are dynamic in lenght. you need to get a `;` or any other sign that is not likely to be used there before 2nd "http://" and then use explode function reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php 
`$string = "http://something.com/;http://something2.com"; $a = explode(";",$string);`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?php
$temp = explode('http://', $test);
foreach($temp as $url) {
    $urls[] = 'http://' . $url;
}
print_r($urls);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = 'http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads//godzilla-article2.jpghttp://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads/life-goes-on-wpcf_300x111.jp';

array_slice(
    array_map(
        function($item) { return "http://" . $item;}, 
        explode("http://",  $test)), 
    1);
```

Answer (score -1):

For answering this question by regular expression I think you want something like this:

```
$test = "http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads//godzilla-article2.jpghttp://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads/life-goes-on-wpcf_300x111.jpg";
    $keywords = preg_split("/.http:\/\//",$test);
    print_r($keywords);
```

It returns exactly something you need:

```
Array
(
 [0] => http://localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads//godzilla-article2.jp
 [1] => localhost/biochem/wp-content/uploads/life-goes-on-wpcf_300x111.jpg
)
```